# Image not shown in tree view , C#

Tags: c#

So in my project i would like have a nice treeview that has images.
but when i run the program the image was not shown. Any idea?
here is my code:

```
 while (thisreader.Read())    // i read from the database.
        {
            TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
        tn.Text = thisreader["channel_name"].ToString();

        tn.ImageIndex = 1;
        tn.SelectedImageIndex = 1;   // i have my imagelist1 in the corresponding winform
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ImageList` must be assigned to the `ImageList` property of the `TreeView` as well. Simply dropping it on the form is not enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
i tried to do the following:

 tn.TreeView.ImageList = imageList1;
 tn.ImageIndex = 0;
 tn.SelectedImageIndex = 0;

It doesn't work tho, could you enlighten me?

Comment: Why not use the designer to assign `imageList1` to the property of the tree view? The way you're doing it, you're re-assigning the image list *every time you add a node*! Also: Are there really images of the correct size in the image list?